# Boot/System partition resizer

Tags: windows, disk-utility

Are there any **free** utilities(like Partition Magic) to resize the boot/system partitions on Windows XP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) [Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). It is OS independent, you just boot it up and resize away. Don't forget to backup first :)

Comment: I highly recommend GParted.

Comment: Is this safe to use with data or an OS installed on one of the partitions?

Comment: @anonymous coward - in my experience, yes. Though it's a good idea to back up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[Easeus](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) has a free home edition